# Jmeter - How to get nested object in json with multiple object

Tags: jmeter, json-path-expression, jsonslurper

I have this json:

```
{
    "deviceId": "deviceCustom",
    "moduleId": "custom",
    "properties": {
        "desired": {
            "settings": {
                "ef78c18c-2291-4d15-ae87-d89abb9b1fef": {
                    "name": "elements",
                    "version": "1.0.0",
                    "category": "A1"
                },
                "f4b04c94-4643-4b13-b10c-9a00fbf4ea27": {
                    "name": "tags",
                    "version": "2.0.0",
                    "category": "B1"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I would like to get separately all the objects under "settings". E.g:

```
settings_1="f4b04c94-4643-4b13-b10c-9a00fbf4ea27":{"name":"tags","version":"2.0.0","category":"B1"}
settings_2="ef78c18c-2291-4d15-ae87-d89abb9b1fef":{"name":"elements","version":"1.0.0","category":"A1"}
settings_matchNr=2
```

In Jmeter I've configured a JSON Extractor with this JSON Path expression: `$.properties.desired.settings` but I got this result:

```
settings_1={"f4b04c94-4643-4b13-b10c-9a00fbf4ea27":{"name":"tags","version":"2.0.0","category":"B1"},"ef78c18c-2291-4d15-ae87-d89abb9b1fef":{"name":"elements","version":"1.0.0","category":"A1"}}
settings_matchNr=1
```

I've also tried to use JSR223 Post Processor with Slurper but no valid result.
Could you help me on that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the request which returns the above JSON
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).properties.desired.settings.entrySet().eachWithIndex { entry, index ->
       def setting = [:]
       setting.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue())
       vars.put('setting_' + (index + 1), new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(setting).toPrettyString())
   }
   ```
3. That's it, you will be able to refer the extracted [JSON Objects](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp) as `${setting_1}` and `${setting_2}`

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)